# What makes msbuild wait another node building the same project?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I've made a test building my project solution twice in parallel to see what happens. Turns out one MSBuild node waits the other to finish before trying to build my solution and then says it's up-to-date. Ex.:

```
<!-- ProjectA.proj -->
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Project Include="MyProject.sln" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="Build" BuildInParallel="true" />
    </Target>
</Project>

<!-- Test.proj -->
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Project Include="ProjectA.proj" />
        <Project Include="ProjectA.proj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="Build" BuildInParallel="true" />
    </Target>
</Project>
<!-- When I check the build log it says 
    1> Project is building MyProject.sln (2) ...
    1> Project is building MyProject.sln (2:2) ...
    2> Building with tools...
    2> ...
    2:2> Building with tools...
    2> ...
    2> ...
    2> ...
    2> Done building
    2:2> Target ... skipped because it was previously built successfully
    2:2> Done building
-->
```

This is a desired behaviour, but when I try to rely on this to make my build workflow oh the build server, my projects are built twice simultaneously, giving me lots of errors.

I do not understand the difference and don't know what to do to find out the problem.

Comment: As "items to build", in your build definition, do you specify a proj file like the example you gave, or do you specify the solution files directly?

Comment: I understood now your question. I specify a project a little bit more complicated than this in the build definition, but with the same idea.